Quarkus3 - JasperReports got java.sql.SQLException: Enlisted connection used without active transaction
we updated our application to Quarkus 3 recently and our report module started to crash on SQLException: Enlisted connection used without active transaction.
2024-07-22T21:24:13.597381608Z executor-thread-1 23 2024-07-22 23:24:13.558  ERROR net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport Fill 1: exception: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error preparing statement for executing the report query:
2024-07-22T21:24:13.597462370Z 
2024-07-22T21:24:13.597475177Z SELECT
2024-07-22T21:24:13.597486237Z     *
2024-07-22T21:24:13.597502662Z FROM
2024-07-22T21:24:13.597519521Z     MY_TABLE
2024-07-22T21:24:13.597530077Z ORDER BY
2024-07-22T21:24:13.597538483Z     col
2024-07-22T21:24:13.597547363Z 
2024-07-22T21:24:13.597555636Z 
2024-07-22T21:24:13.597574220Z  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createStatement(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:555)
2024-07-22T21:24:13.597810783Z  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:299)
2024-07-22T21:24:13.598088743Z  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1317)
2024-07-22T21:24:13.598244727Z  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:767)
2024-07-22T21:24:13.598340997Z  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.setParameters(BaseReportFiller.java:465)
2024-07-22T21:24:13.598391111Z  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:585)
2024-07-22T21:24:13.598464565Z  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:416)
2024-07-22T21:24:13.598525214Z  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:827)
2024-07-22T21:24:13.598583947Z  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:61)
2024-07-22T21:24:13.598621143Z  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:221)
2024-07-22T21:24:13.598716311Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
2024-07-22T21:24:13.598803387Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
2024-07-22T21:24:13.598913843Z  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
2024-07-22T21:24:13.599023284Z Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Enlisted connection used without active transaction
2024-07-22T21:24:13.599110173Z  at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionHandler.verifyEnlistment(ConnectionHandler.java:398)
2024-07-22T21:24:13.599149982Z  at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.ConnectionWrapper.getMetaData(ConnectionWrapper.java:452)
2024-07-22T21:24:13.599212173Z  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.OracleProcedureCallHandler.isOracle(OracleProcedureCallHandler.java:72)
2024-07-22T21:24:13.599341106Z  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.isProcedureCall(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:566)
2024-07-22T21:24:13.599481640Z  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createStatement(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:389)
2024-07-22T21:24:13.599597852Z  ... 12 more


same code worked with quarkus 2
JasperReports 7 is used to secure jakarta packages
the transaction is active until the connection is given to Jasper engine
I tried to start transaction manually using  QuarkusTransaction.begin() righ before JasperFillManager call - but it resulted in "transaction already active" error

I checked the sources and found out that JasperFillManager.fillReport is a static method, that could explain a transaction loss.
https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/7.0.0/core/src/main/java/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.java#L922
But calling fill method directly din't help and resulted in the same error as mentioned above
JasperFillManager manager = JasperFillManager.getInstance ( DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance() );
JasperPrint print = manager.fill(reportFile, parameters, con);

Do you guys have any idea why our reports crash?
Any kind of information is hugely appreciated.
Thank you

Feels like there was a call to jasper side with @Transactional before from Quarkus 2 with Quarkus 3 that changed and jasper complaining about no active transaction, can you put a small reproducer ?
